# On RH in the Clay Institute list

Tags: open-problems, riemann-hypothesis, navier-stokes

As everybody knows, the Riemann Hypothesis is one of the problems of the millenium raised by the Clay Institute. Looking at the "official formulation" of various problems, say for instance for Navier-Stokes system for incompressible fluids, we see in the C.L. Fefferman's formulation a clearcut list of four questions (A), (B), (C), (D) (blow-up or not in the periodic 3D or in $\mathbb R^3$) with two "positive" (global existence of smooth solutions for  all smooth compactly supported initial data) questions and two "negative" (possible blow-up for some smooth compactly supported initial data) questions.

Nothing of the sort is happening with E. Bombieri's description of RH: in fact, no precise question is raised, although the reader finds a very nice account of the state-of-the art on RH and also in another document by P. Sarnak a much more detailed exposition: obviously the question is "positive" and is "Prove that the Riemann Hypothesis holds true." So somehow, a potential disproof of RH is not to be counted by the Clay Institute as an achievement of the same magnitude as an actual proof of RH. I would be curious to know if my way of reading is shared by some other people.

Comment: Your reading is correct, the task is to prove the RH. If a disproof is found, then item 5c of the official rules will take into effect: https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/millennium_prize_rules_0.pdf

Comment: @GHfromMO I can read in this 5c: *if a counterexample is proposed, such
counterexample shall be evaluated using the same evaluation procedure as if it were
a Proposed Solution.
**(i)**. If, in the opinion of CMI, the counterexample effectively resolves the Problem,
then CMI may recommend the award of a Prize.
**(ii)**. If, alternatively, the counterexample shows that the original Problem survives
after reformulation or elimination of some special case, then CMI may
recommend that a small prize, of an amount to be determined by CMI in its
sole discretion, be awarded to the author.*

Comment: My guess, given the fact that RH is highly expected to hold literally, is that (i) would apply rather than (ii). Any negative solution to RH would be a revolution, compelling to deeply revise our intuition of the picture. Anyway the rules say that some discussion would be engaged by the board to settle this.

Comment: @YCor: I disagree.

Comment: @YCor The paragraph 5c is a provision to exclude something like the [ZetaGrid project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZetaGrid) finding a nontrivial zero. My impression is that CMI's goal is to reward a nontrivial piece of mathematics, rather than a (comparatively trivial) computation. If a counterexample is found computationally, my wild guess is that the problem would get modified to something along the lines of "are there only finitely many zeros off the line?", which couldn't be done with a simple computation (unless done so after a reduction of the problem.)

Comment: @GHfromMO RH could be unproved by a complicated argument, for example by a very careful study of the behaviour of $\pi(x)$ something as the elementary proof of the prime number theorem but more complicated. In this case the prize will be well deserved I think.

Comment: @juan: I agree. My comment was that a disproof of RH will not necessarily lead to awarding the full Millenium prize reserved for the RH. Like Wojowu said.

Comment: @YCor : I agree with GH from MO and Wojowu. If it were the committee's opinion that "Any negative solution of RH would be a revolution" then it would have included RH alongside P v. NP and Navier-Stokes in 5b. I would go as far as to say that RH's absence from 5b is so conspicuous as to be a clear indication that its omission from 5b is intentional.

Comment: If RH is false, it really matters how false it is and how one figures that out; for example, if some computational method that can probe the zeroes at $T$ around $10^{10^{1000}}$ - where counterexamples are likelier than at much lower values of $T$ - if indeed RH false - finds a noncritical line zero (or similarly but for the Hardy function in that range finding a Lehmer counterexample, so a negative local maximum or a positive local minimum), surely that will tell us something but not that much as opposed to say proving that there are infinitely many exceptions etc